# Select/distort a single anchor point of a group in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

With a normal shape, I can select one corner using the direct selection tool and drag to distort:

[image]

to

[image]

I want to apply the same type of single-point dragging distortion to the bounding box of a group of shapes, but can't figure out any way to do it.

[image]

How could I select the right-bottom corner of this group, and drag to distort the whole group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update

With CC2017, the **Free Transform Tool** has a cursor specifically for **Free Distort**. You can just select that cursor and perform the same distortion without the need for any modifier keys.

[image]

The modifier will still work in CC2017, but should you have trouble, switching cursors is the easiest thing to do.

---

## Other Methods

## <sup>(or for legacy versions of Illustrator Prior to CC2014)</sup>

You **must** use the **Free Transform** tool.

1. Select all 4 objects
2. Select the Free Transform Tool
3. Click and hold a corner
4. ***then*** hold the Command/Ctrl key
5. ***then*** drag to perform the distortion

You ***must*** do things in this specific order - click, hold key, drag - Any other order will not work. This will not work with the standard bounding box. You must use the **Free Transform tool**.

[image: distort]

Another option, although without a live preview, is....

1. Group the 4 objects
2. Then choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Free Distort`

[image: effect]

Comment: Scott! You the man. This is really tricky because of the order and because the cursor gives no indicator. Works perfect- thanks---

Comment: Yes it is a bit tricky, but once you get used to it, it becomes second nature. Other keys do different things, try Command/Ctrl+Option/Alt - with and without shift... etc. You'll get various distortions.

Comment: Please reread the answer @Unrelated It works in all version of Illustrator currently available (CC2017 as of this writing). But it is rather finicky and tricky to implement until you get the hang of it. With the Free Transform tool, CC2017 has a "free distort" cursor which you can merely select and use.